# Executing SQL Scripts in a batch

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, batch-file

I have about 100 scripts that needs to be executed on SSMS. How can i execute them as a batch instead of executing each individually.

I tried using this but it didn't work.

```
@echo off
ECHO %USERNAME% started the batch process at %TIME%  >output.txt


FOR %%? in ("1.01*.SQL") DO 
 (
sqlcmd.exe  -S local -E   -d collect -i %%? >>output.txt
)

pause
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following runs all scripts in a directory, output data to a .log file and errors to a .err.log file:

```
@echo off
echo "Enter Server"
set /p SERVER=

echo "Enter Database"
set /p DATABASE=

if exist *.log ( del *.log )

rem Process the files
for %%i in (*.sql) do osql -E -S %SERVER% -d %DATABASE% -i"%%i" -m0 -w500 -I -b -r  -o"%%i.log"  2>%%i.err.log

rem Remove empty .err files (ie had no errors)
for %%a in (*.err.log) do if %%~za==0 del "%%a"


pause
```

Note: An earlier version of this used `sqlcmd` however there proved to be issues with sqlcmd missing out data in the output logs.

Comment: I ran the batch so it created a .SQl file for each script and i looked at the file and it has values like: 1> 2> 3> 4> 5>. And it didn't create any log file or error log file

Comment: You will be seeing ".sql" because you've not got the setting enabled to show file extensions in windows explorer. The file names are appended with .log, so they end up as "myscript.sql.log" for example. The 1>2>3> is the output from osql.

Answer (score 0):

> To all:
>
> I found some issues with the above, Like Windows 7 Dos did not like the %%i or %%a so I removed an '%' character an then the dos script started to work just fine.
>
> Below is my actual running version of the script where the "1.A00*.SQL" script run truncates my target tables.
>
> The "A*.SQL" run script A01_name.sql --> A24_name.sql sequentially, which is quite nice
>
> Hank Freeman hfreeman@msn.com
>
> end.
>
> REM " FSA_3.2.2_Runner_for_Insert_Scripts.bat
>
> Rem " Script runner "
>
> Rem " How to use this script"
>
> Rem " From a Remote Desktop session Open a Dos Prompt"
>
> Rem " Run the below script"
>
> Rem " Validate the data has been inserted."
>
> Rem " Hank Freeman July 15th 2014 hfreeman@msn.com"
>
> Rem " *** begin ***"
>
> c:
>
> cd \
>
> cd C:\Database_Scripts\Insert_Scripts
>
> @echo off
>
> if exist *.log ( del *.log )
>
> rem "** Starting here ***"
>
> rem "run the Truncate SQL file"
>
> for %i in (1.A00_*.SQL) do osql -E   -i"%i" -m0 -w500 -I -b -r  -o"%i.log"  2>%i.err.log
>
> rem "run the A01-A24 SQL file"
>
> for %i in (A*.SQL) do osql -E   -i"%i" -m0 -w500 -I -b -r  -o"%i.log"  2>%i.err.log
>
> rem Remove empty .err files (ie had no errors)
>
> for %a in (*.err.log) do if %~za==0 del "%a"
>
> rem "Remove the logs - Manual operation"
>
> rem if exist *.log ( del *.log )
>
> Rem " *** end ***"
>
> @echo on